# I'm trying to read memory of a process but for some reason I'm not getting the right size of the process memory - what's wrong?

Tags: c#, winforms

This is the code in Form1:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace MemoryScanner
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {


        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern Int32 ReadProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress,
            [In, Out] byte[] buffer, UInt32 size, out IntPtr lpNumberOfBytesRead);

        public static byte[] ReadBytes(IntPtr Handle, Int64 Address, uint BytesToRead)
        {
            IntPtr ptrBytesRead;
         //   ptrBytesRead = (IntPtr)30;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[BytesToRead];
            ReadProcessMemory(Handle, new IntPtr(Address), buffer, BytesToRead, out ptrBytesRead);

            Array.Resize<byte>(ref buffer, ptrBytesRead.ToInt32());
            return buffer;
        }

        public static int ReadInt32(long Address, uint length = 4, IntPtr? Handle = null)
        {
            return BitConverter.ToInt32(ReadBytes((IntPtr)Handle, Address, length), 0);
        }

        public static string ReadString(long Address, uint length = 32, IntPtr? Handle = null)
        {
            string temp3 = ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetString(ReadBytes((IntPtr)Handle, Address, length));
            string[] temp3str = temp3.Split('\0');
            return temp3str[0];
        }


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Process p = null;
            UInt32 Address = 00002688;
            // get process
            Process[] Processes = Process.GetProcesses();
            List<Process> flash_processes = new List<Process>();
            for (int i = 0; i < Processes.Length; i++)
            {
                //IntPtr f = Test[i].MainModule.BaseAddress;// Are you sure you want the flag  process ? 
                p = Processes[i];
                if (p.ProcessName.StartsWith("FlashPlugin") == true)
                    flash_processes.Add(p);
            }
            Process Test = flash_processes[1]; // take the second flash process .. are you sure about that? we need the second process ?


            p = Candy;




            UInt32 proc_base_addr = (UInt32)p.MainModule.BaseAddress.ToInt32();//+00000+1835008+100000;
            uint proc_mem_sz = (uint)p.MainModule.ModuleMemorySize;

//            byte[] arr = ReadBytes(p.Handle, proc_base_addr, proc_mem_sz);

            byte[] arr = ReadBytes(p.Handle, proc_base_addr, proc_mem_sz);//5 * 1024 * 1024);
```

The project is under Admin.
The size i'm getting arr is: 1888256 also the variable proc_mem_sz contain: 1888256

When i'm using the windows Task Manager i see two processes one it's memory size: 78.1MB
The second one is: 3.1MB

The problem is that i can't get the specific process memory size.
I need it to read all the memory of a specific process.

Answer (score 1):

`ModuleMemorySize` indicates the amount of memory that is required to load the module. It includes only the size of the static code and data in the module file, but no additional allocations made from the module after it's been loaded.

To get detailed information about the memory usage of a process you should look at [GetProcessMemoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683219%28VS.85%29.aspx). You can find an example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682050%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

You can retrieve information about the current working set (the amount of memory physically mapped to its process context) with [QueryWorkingSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684946%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) \ [QueryWorkingSetEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684949%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687398%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Marius ok . Could you show me then how to use it how to make additional allocations made from the module after it's been loaded ? I know that something is missing/wrong with my code.

Comment: You should explain first what you are trying to achieve. Reading the whole memory of a process? Why?

Comment: Marius the reason i'm trying to read the whole memory of a process is so i can later to scan the memory for a specific areas for a specific values. The problem is that i can't get the whole mamory for a specific process.

Comment: Did you check the other functions I pointed in my edited post?

Comment: @DoronMuzar there are a lot of examples around on how to do that. There is even example code for that in the Win32 SDK (now Platform SDk, AFIAK). Look for "Walker". And there is the old but excellent book by Jeffrey Richter (Advanced Windows), which is definitely worth a read if you are doing something so "dangerous".